# Can I write a PCRE conditional that only needs the no-match part?

Tags: db2, db2-400, icu

I am trying to create a regular expression to determine if a string contains a number for an SQL statement. If the value is numeric, then I want to add 1 to it. If the number is not numeric, I want to return a 1. More or less. Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT 
   field,
   CASE
     WHEN regexp_like(field, '^ *\d*\.?\d* *$') THEN dec(field) + 1
     ELSE 1
   END nextnumber
FROM mytable
```

This actually works, and returns something like this:

```
INVALID     1
00000       1
00001E      1
00379       380
00013       14
99904       99905
```

But to push the envelope of understanding, what if I wanted to cover negative numbers, or those with a positive sign. The sign would have to immediately precede or follow the number, but not both, and I would not want to allow white space between the sign and the number.

I came up with a conditional expression with a capture group to capture the sign on the front of the number to determine if a sign was allowed on the end, but it seems a little awkward to handle given I don't really need a yes-pattern.

Here is the modified regex: `^ ([+-]?)*\d*\.?\d*(?(1) *|[+-]? *)$`

This works at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), but in order for it to work I need to have something before the pipe, so I have to **duplicate the next pattern** in both the `yes-pattern` and the `no-pattern`.

All that background for this question: How can I avoid that duplication?

---

**EDIT:** DB2 for i uses International Components for Unicode to provide regular expression processing. It turns out that this library does not support conditionals like PRCE, so I changed the tags on this question. The answer given by Wiktor Stribiżew provides a working alternative to the conditional by using a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to duplicate the end pattern, just move it outside the conditional:

```
^ *([+-])?\d*\.?\d*(?(1)|[+-]?) *$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQ6cTz/2/). So, the yes-part is empty, and the no-part has an optional pattern.

You may also solve it with a mere negative lookahead:

```
^ *([+-](?!.*[-+]))?\d*\.?\d*[+-]? *$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQ6cTz/1). Here, `([+-](?!.*[-+]))?` matches (optionally) a `+` or `-` that are not followed with any 0+ char followed with another `+` or `-`.

Comment: This really helps with the lookahead/lookbehind stuff I have read. That is a piece of pcre that I have been very foggy about.

Comment: Turns out that the conditional does not work with DB2 for i. I cannot find any documentation that tells me that it shouldn't work, I just can't make it work. DB2 for i uses the International Components for Unicode library to provide regular expression parsing, so conditionals should work, I just can't find the magic incantation. The negative look ahead works great though.